# Problem displaying $_POST data with session

Tags: php

I have a form which collects user info including name, location, url, email address etc etc AND company logo AND appropriate catagories they wish to be associated with (using a checkbox array in $_POST).

I then display a preview of the page (using $_SESSION and hidden form fields to hold the $_POST data) which their data will appear on BEFORE storing it in MySQL with an 'approve' button which links to the PHP page which has the MySQL INSERT query.

The problem i'm having is the preview page in between entry and submission to the database is having trouble with the logo input and the checkbox array input:

```
$_SESSION['clogo'] = $_POST['clogo'];
$_SESSION['cat[]'] = $_POST['cat[]'];
```

I get an 'undefined index' error when i try to preview these, however all other standard input is fine, and is then passed along to the insert mysql query on user approval. In addition, if i skip the 'preview page' and go straight to the insert PHP file from the original form, there is no problem, and all data is entered into the database correctly.

Can anyone help

Comment: Removed the mysql tag.  It doesn't really matter what you're going to do with the data later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `$_POST['cat']` is an array in itself. (I'm guessing this because of the `[]` following `cat` in your example.) If this is the case, then in your example, you're setting `$_SESSION['cat[]']` equal to a variable name that doesn't exist. Try setting `$_SESSION['cat']` equal to `$_POST['cat']`.

Comment: Are you allowing them to upload an image? If so, you need to work with the files in the temporary directory. Take a look at the `$_FILES` array after the `POST` for the `tmp_name`. You'll have to move the file using `move_uploaded_file`. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Well thats sorted the error message out for the array but now it doesn't store the selected items from the array (there are six checkboxes) in the database, it stores all of them! Any ideas?

Comment: `print_r($_POST['cat'])` before setting it to the session variable. Make sure your form is posting correctly.

Comment: Hi Michael, this is my code on the insert page for the image move_uploaded_file($_FILES["clogo"]["tmp_name"], "avatars/" . $_FILES["clogo"]["name"]); On the preview page i simply have  $_SESSION['clogo'] = $_POST['clogo']; for the uploaded image, where will its temporary location be?

Comment: You're moving it, so that's good. When you're setting the `$_POST['clogo'] = $_SESSION['clogo']`, that's only the name of the file. On your preview page, you need to put in the correct path. `<img src="avatars/".$_SESSION['clogo']."" />`

Comment: it outputs this with the the additon of the print_r command: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) which looks correct as i selected the first three checkboxes with those values.

Comment: @Dan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1154/discussion-between-mririgo-and-dan)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want this:

```
$_SESSION['cat[]'] = $_POST['cat[]'];
```

But this:

```
$_SESSION['cat'] = $_POST['cat'];
```

I.e., 'cat' is the index of the _POST array, and the element that it refers to is another array.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to start the session using the `start_session` function. Otherwise nothing will be saved in the session.

Also worth noting is that when using some third party application they might remove all session variables. Wordpress is a good example.

Comment: hi @Ancide, well i'm using session_start() and i'm having no problem with any of the other fields, either previewing them, or adding them to the database on approval, its just the uploaded image and the checkbox array which is not playing ball. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$_POST[] array must be re-initialize, as you are posting to preview page and then php insert script page...
When you go directly from form to php script page ,POST have variables in it, so it must be working fine.

Comment: OP says "hidden form fields to hold the $_POST data".

Answer (score 0):

'cat[]' would not be the index.  The index would be 'cat' which should be an array.